# How to create a database schema for multiple dropdown lists of multiple options

Tags: database, database-design

Say you have a table of computer models, these computer models can have different parts upgraded such as ram, cpu and storage and the different options available are stored in dropdown lists.

How would you represent this in a database?

I was thinking of individual table for each type such as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ram(
    primary_key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    size TEXT NOT NULL,
    price REAL NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cpu(
    primary_key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    cpu_type TEXT NOT NULL,
    price REAL NOT NULL
);
```

But then how do I group multiple records of these together to create a drop down grouping? Do I need a separate table for each option that stores all the primary keys for one dropdown list group? Or can I group them in one options table? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As a guiding principle, prefer more columns over more tables, and prefer more rows over more columns. That's because each preference is easier to implement and manage than the other option.

The problem with your approach is every time you have a new type of thing, you'll need a new table. That will require a schema change and new code to deal with it. Importantly, these new things will not be discoverable by your app.

Instead, create a table for all things:

```
create table part (
    id int,
    name varchar(99),
    price real
    -- more columns for attributes that ALL parts have (if any)
)
```

Since different parts have different attributes, it's not sensible to have lots of columns in this table, most of which are not used. Create tables for the special attributes:

```
create table part_attr (
    part_id int references part(id),
    name varchar(99),
    value varchar(99)
    -- possibly other columns
)
```

Then use code to weave it all together into dropdown etc.

Comment: This solution violated 1st Normal Form.

Comment: @PaulTrimor not only is it not violating 1NF, it’s actually 3NF. The key of the part table is (of course) `id`. The key of part_attr table is (of course) the compound key `(part_id, name)`.